# Create user defined attributes using hash - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

I have my Profile Migration like this :

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :detail
      t.boolean :visible
      t.timestamps
      end
    add_index :profiles, :detail
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :profiles
  end
end
```

And I have a `User has_one Profile` and `Profile belongs_to User` Relation.

Now, I want to store the Profile details as serialized. So I have the Profile class like this :

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :detail, Hash
end
```

This is because I want each user to be able to create different profile details, something like this

```
Profile.new.detail ={:education => ["Degree", true], :Hobby => ["Music", false] }
```

Now, since I have user_id has the other attribute, what command can I use for users to add new details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Profile has_many Details`:

```
p = Profile.new
p.detail = []
p.detail << {:'Linked In Profile' => ["link", false]}
p.detail << {education: [...]}
```

For `Profile has_one Detail`:

```
Profile.new.detail = { :Education => ["Degree", true], :'Linked In Profile' => ["link", false] }
```

Comment: Thanks, Profile.new.detail = { :education => ["", true], :Town => ["Cook", false] } this works but hw can I save the user_id also along with it, since each user will have separate profile attributes !!

Comment: you want a `Profile` to have many `details`? Each with attributes of it's `Profile`?

Comment: `Profile.new.detail = {education: true, user_id: @user.id}`, but I don't know why would you do that.

Comment: detail is actually an attribute inside Profile model. I want user to be able to create his own list of  info -detail pair. So I am storing the detail attribute as hash.

Comment: then `@user.profile.build.tap {|p| p.detail = {education: true, user_id: @user.id}}`

Comment: fine but now the issue is if I do { :Linked In => ["http://linkedin.com", true]} it gives me an error since :Linked In not being a single word will break. SO if u look at the updated question, I add a new field visible to set the boolean there and somehow get both detail label and value inside the hash. So how could I get that done ?

Comment: `>> {:'look a dis' => true}['look a dis'] #=> nil` notice that it's a symbol with spaces and string features

Comment: Didnt get you can u convert this line in the format u mentioned Profile.new.detail = { :Education => ["Degree", true], :Linked In Profile => ["link", false] } since it will not work :Linked in Profile will break since it is not a single word

Comment: let's not discuss it here, form your question better and I'll update my answer solving the space error

Comment: Yes i need to pass it as a string !! Got it Thanks !!